# How to use dataset.map in Tensorflow Data API correctly

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm learning how to use the Tensorflow Data API, and struggle to understand how mapping works. For the context, I want to load a dataset of images and send them to a neural network.

The MWE below does that in idea (fake dataset of size 10, `read_image` function mapped to the dataset).

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


def read_image(filename, label):
    return np.random.rand(8, 8, 1), label # simulate data load (generate random data)

# generate fake dataset of filenames (of size 10)
filenames = tf.constant(np.asarray(["file" + str(i) for i in range(10)]))
labels = tf.constant(np.asarray([2*i for i in range(10)]))

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((filenames, labels))
dataset = dataset.map(read_image)

dataset = dataset.repeat().batch(2)
iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(dataset.output_types, dataset.output_shapes)


X, y = iterator.get_next()
train_init_op = iterator.make_initializer(dataset)

with tf.Session() as session:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    session.run(train_init_op)
    for _ in range(10):
        print(session.run([X]))
```

When running this code (that is supposed to do nothing, just print the values generated by `read_image`), it ends up with always the same data: `read_image` is called only once. Why is that ? I used `dataset.map`, isn't it supposed to be called on every element of my dataset (10 here) ?

Thanks in advance for any help or advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding of it was wrong, I actually figured out how to make it work. This map function is "integrated" to the Tensorflow graph, hence indeed called just once. One need to use TF operations in it.

If `read_image` is replaced by:

```
def read_image(filename, label):
    return tf.random_normal([4]), tf.random_normal([1])
```

It works as expected (random values are generated each time `session.run` is called).

Comment: In addition, I guess that what I was trying to do could have been achieved using `tf.py_func()`